# Loading Chinese character to DB2 using SQL Insert statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, db2

I need to use `VBA excel macro` to load Chinese character data from excel spreadsheet to DB2 using SQL Insert Statement. I know that this cannot work with normal Insert statement as below:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
       VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Since this is my first time dealing with double byte character, can anybody help to guide me on which method I can use to load `DBCS data into DB2`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `VALUES ("N'" & value1 & "', N'" & value2 & "', N'" & ...` - The `N`prefix makes sure you insert Unicoded values.

Comment: Your assumption that "this cannot work with normal Insert statement" is incorrect.

Comment: Why can't you do this. I do it everyday.

Comment: I cannot use direct Insert Statement as it will show as ???.

Comment: Hi @LocEngineer, I tried using the N prefix in VBA macro, but the wording after that get commented with the use of apostrophe. I tried putting the value in " " but the data get input in the database as it is (which is N'xxx').

Comment: Also, to add to my original question, I am inserting the Chinese data to IBM OS/390. The connection from excel to the IBM OS/390 mainframe was established by DB2. 
I am using connection string 
CnStr = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=" & Password + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & UserId + ";Data Source=" & Db + ";Mode=ReadWrite;

*Apologize if my explanation is confusing as I am no expert to the programming world.

Comment: Please post your VBA lines where you try to insert. What you posted above is a pseudo SQL string. For VBA you need to put it all in a string and concatenate where you pull in dynamic values or, better yet, use a parametrized query. Without proper code we are only stumbling in the blind.

Comment: Hi @LocEngineer, This is my Insert statement in VBA:

oStr = "INSERT INTO "  & tableName &  " ( " & field1 &  "," & field2 & ") Values(" & data1 "," & " N' " & data2 & " ')" 

where field1, field2, value1 and value2 values are from excel spreadsheet. 

When I use this, I got error "[IBM][CLI Driver][SQLDS/VM] SQL0105N The string constant beginning with "" is not valid. SQLSTATE=42604"

If I put the N' delimiter inside the double quote, then it will direct insert the N delimeter as part of the chinese character data.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Not knowing your table and column names, enclose them with square brackets to be on the safe side
2. There must be no space between the `N'` prefix and the Unicode data, nor a space after the value itself
3. Your `data1` value is not enclosed in quotation marks; this means it must be a numeric value. If it is not a numeric value, enclose it in quotation marks. If it is a Unicode string, enclose it in `"N'..."'"`

Try with this:

```
oStr = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "] ([" & field1 & "], [" & field2 & "]) Values(" & data1 "," & " N'" & data2 & "');"
```